# Does it make sense to create promise from StompClient SEND request?

Tags: angularjs, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I want to make additional request to server after SEND message through StompClient was successfully maintained.

```
function sendActivity() {
        connected.promise.then(function () {
            stompClient
                .send('/app/activity',
                    {},
                    angular.toJson(/*some data*/));
        }).finally(function () {
            /*additional Rest request to Server */
        });
    }
```

It's currently working on my local machine but i'm not sure that operations are working synchronously as i wanted. 
Could you please assist with my sitiation?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. It's better to wait for ack from server for your 'app/activity' message and then do other stuffs.